# Power series of $\ln{(x + \sqrt{1+x^2})}$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Well, the title states the problem, so let's get to it.

First of all I've calculated the derivative of the given function:

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Now, we know that:

$$(1+x)^m = 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{m\cdot(m-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(m-n+1)}{n!}\cdot x^n}$$

Therefore:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = (1+x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-\frac{1}{2})\cdot(-\frac{3}{2})\cdot \cdot \cdot (-\frac{1}{2}-n+1)}{n!}\cdot x^{2n}} = 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{2} \cdot \cdot \cdot \frac{2n-1}{2}}{n!}\cdot x^{2n}}$$
Now I'm following a solution from my textbook, and I've managed to follow it up until here. This is where the above expression becomes:

$$=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n\cdot(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}}\cdot x^{2n}$$

with no explanation given. How was this transformation made? This is in fact the only part of the solution I don't understand, integrating the final sum and thereby getting the power series is no problem, it's just this transformation I can't get through my head.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the fact that\begin{align}(2n)!!&=(2n)\times(2n-2)\times\cdots\times4\times2\\&=2^n\times n\times(n-1)\times\cdots\times2\times1.\end{align}and that$$(2n-1)!!=(2n-1)\times(2n-3)\times\cdots\times3\times1.$$

Comment: I might be an idiot here, but I gotta ask: is x!! not the same as (x!)! ?

Comment: **No!!** (pun intended): $n!!$ is the product of all natural numbers smaller than or equal to $n$ *which have the same parity as* $n$.

Comment: Good one!!
Well I guess 30 seconds of googling would've saved me from having to write an entire question. Thanks

Comment: What would happen if the answer was "**No!!!**"? $\ddot\smile$.